# Hosting 50+ websites with Node.js backend (stack: Forever, Express, Nginx & Let's Encrypt)

Tags: node.js, nginx

I plan on hosting multiple websites using the Node.js Express server(s?). Is it good practice to create a server.js file for each website in the root of the website?

e.g. `/var/www/example1.com/server.js`   &  `/var/www/example2.com/server.js.`

**example server.js:**

```
const express = require('express')  
const app = express()  
const port = 3000 // 1 port for each website

app.get('/', (request, response) => {  
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

**Cronjob with rule to start each server -- works like a charm**

```
#!/bin/sh
export NODE_ENV=production
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

for line in $(find /var/www/*/server.js); do
   forever start $line > /dev/null
done
```

Comment: are these all different websites? different codebases?

Comment: Yes, all are different websites connected to a single database and some  just static.

Comment: Just a thought - but you may want to keep "node_modules" separate - otherwise you have 50+ websites to test if you upgrade a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need a different `server.js` for all the websites, as they all are likely to handle different requests/have different APIs/different routing.

Also, if you have to restart the server for a particular website, if you use just one `server.js`, all your websites would be down during the restart, versus just the one that needs changes if they all have different `server.js`s.